# Python3 How can I decide which variable will be modified?

Tags: string, multithreading, variables, python-3.x

I'm working on a multithreaded simulator script, where bots from team A are fighting with team B. All the TeamA bots are attacking an opponent (from TeamB) with lowest number, until it dies and then they (should) shift from attacking for example TeamB1_hitpoints to TeamB2_hitpoints.

To accomplish that, I tried using strings, but it doesn't work. Why I tried it this way is because I use a separate "supervisor" thread that decides which opponent should be attacked by all bots from TeamA and TeamB and writes it to a variable like this(this is what my "supervisor" thread looks like):

```
    class S1(threading.Thread):
    def run(self): 
        S1loopcount=0
        global ingame, TeamA_target, TeamB_target
        while positive(A1_hitpoints+A2_hitpoints+A3_hitpoints) > 0 and positive(B1_hitpoints+B2_hitpoints+B3_hitpoints) > 0:
    while (TeamA1_hitpoints+TeamA2_hitpoints+TeamA3_hitpoints) > 0 and ingame=1: 
      if TeamB1_hitpoints > 0:
        TeamA_target="TeamB1"
      else:
        if TeamB2_hitpoints > 0:
          TeamA_target="TeamB2"
        else:
          if TeamB3_hitpoints > 0:
            TeamA_target="TeamB3"
    while (TeamB1_hitpoints+TeamB2_hitpoints+TeamB3_hitpoints) > 0 and ingame=1:
      if TeamA1_hitpoints > 0:
        TeamB_target="TeamA1"
      else:
        if TeamA2_hitpoints > 0:
          TeamB_target="TeamA2"
        else:
          if TeamA3_hitpoints > 0:
            TeamB_target="TeamA3"

    ingame=0
```

And the actual bot threads look somehow like this:

```
class BotA1(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global ...yeah, declaring many variables
        while TeamA1_hitpoints>0 and ingame = 1
            if #???# > 0:
                    #???#=(#???#-20)
                    time.sleep(1)
```

And #???# is the problematic part, because I initially imagined it to be something like:

```
int(str(TeamA_target)_hitpoints)
```

So that the supervisor thread can decide, which bot should be attacked by whole team. I imagined, that it would behave like "TeamB1_hitpoints","TeamB2_hitpoints" or "teamB3_hitpoints", so it would be interpreted by the program as a name of a variable.

I also tried experimenting with strings like:

```
int(str("{0}_hitpoints".format(TeamA_target)))
```

But I still can't get it to work. I just need to make teamA and teamB attack a certain opponent bot, based on supervisor's decission. Can this be done by some operation on vatiables/strings? 
Any working solution (possibly the easiest one, cause I'm a noob) highly appreciated :3
Big thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on how `dicts` work. That way you can do things like `teamA["hitpoints"]` or `teamB["target"]`

Comment: If I imagine it right, then I could also do things like
TeamA["bot1","hitpoints"] and TeamB["shared","target"]? 
This sounds good, but I have no idea how it could solve my problem yet. Thank You, I'm gonna read about it :3

Comment: Yes, read up on how `dicts` work in python. The correct syntax would be `TeamA["bot1"]["hitpoints"]`, `TeamA["bot2"]["hitpoints"]`, etc.

Comment: Multi threaded simulators get very quickly very complicated (just ask the people working in vhdl/verilog sims) - doesn't seem necessary here so why complicate things?

Comment: That's because:
1. Every bot is configurable under every aspect(firerate, damage, hp...), what can make it unique... and to me, it's easier to imagine it this way.
2. Multicore CPU scalability- I like scalable applications very much and I'd rather learn how to make them, than something IMO old-fashioned.

Also, I experimented a bit with dicts and it seems to be the solution I've been looking for. Thanks;)